# Javascript replace ' with \'

Tags: javascript, replace

I've got this string in javascript:

```
var s = "pippo'";
```

I want my string to become:

```
"pippo\'"
```

If I do a replace:

```
s = s.replace("'","\\'");
```

it becomes:

```
"pippo\\'"
```

if I do a replace like this:

```
s = s.replace("'","\'");
```

it remains:

```
"pippo'"
```

Ho can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the place you're viewing the result that's showing you the escaped version?  ie if you do `"pippo'".replace("'","\\'")` in the console, it'll show you the escaped version, but if you log or alert it, it's as you expect.

Comment: You are confusing string's representation with its actual content. Try `console.log(s)` after doing `s = s.replace("'","\\'");`

Comment: What do you want for the *string content*? `pippo'` or `pippo\'`? Because right now you seem to be confusing string *content* with the *representation*. E.g., `console.log("pippo\\'")` would give you `pippo\'` - content and representation are different. And depending on how you print the string, you might get a different representation.